# pod install error on react native project

Tags: react-native, cocoapods

When I `cd ios && pod install`, I keep getting this error.

I tried several things like
delete `node_modules` and `yarn install` again, `yarn cache clean`, `pod deintegrate`, etc., but no luck.

```
❯ pod install
error Failed to load configuration of your project.

[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: 859: unexpected token at 'Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat '/Users/user/dev/fondee-rn-webview/ios/node_modules/@bam.tech/react-native-make'

    at Object.lstatSync (node:fs:1514:3)

    at /Users/user/dev/fondee-rn-webview/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:319:16

    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/dev/fondee-rn-webview/node_modules/@bam.tech/react-native-make/react-native.config.js:9:13)

    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1101:14)

    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)

    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)

    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)

    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)

    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)

    at module.exports (/Users/user/dev/fondee-rn-webview/node_modules/cosmiconfig/node_modules/import-fresh/index.js:28:9)

info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
'.

 #  from /Users/user/dev/fondee-rn-webview/ios/Podfile:24
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  target 'fondee' do
 >    config = use_native_modules!
 #  
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

How can I successfully install pod?
I did update all the packages (`yarn upgrade --latest`).

Here is my package.json:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@notifee/react-native": "7.2.0",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.17.10",
    "@react-native-clipboard/clipboard": "^1.8.5",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^16.4.6",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^16.4.6",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.26",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.6",
    "react-native-device-info": "^10.3.0",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.6.1",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-send-intent": "^1.3.0",
    "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-webview": "^11.15.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@bam.tech/react-native-make": "^3.0.3",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.2.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.4",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.70.7",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.3.1",
    "eslint": "^8.29.0",
    "jest": "^29.3.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.73.4",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "typescript": "^4.4.4"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "^18.0.26"
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

The error is occurring because `@bam.tech/react-native-make` does not have pod file. Why are you using this package? The package is old and has only 20 weekly downloads.
You can follow [this](https://blog.logrocket.com/splash-screen-react-native/) blog to create splash screens.

Comment: yep, you're right. I should remake splash screen and app icon following that link's instruction, thank you!